# Error: org.apache.http.MalformedChunkCodingException: Unexpected content at the end of chunk

Tags: tomcat, jmeter

I am running a load testing on my server using JMeter and I got a lot of error like below

```
org.apache.http.MalformedChunkCodingException: Unexpected content at the end of chunk
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.getChunkSize(ChunkedInputStream.java:244)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.nextChunk(ChunkedInputStream.java:209)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:171)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:201)
at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:155)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.readResponse(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1745)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPAbstractImpl.readResponse(HTTPAbstractImpl.java:412)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:352)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1135)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:434)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What is the reason causing this error?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try working this around by using different "Implementation" of the underlying HTTP transport. Change it to `Java` or `HTTPClient3.1`.

The best option to do it in a single shot is using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://blazemeter.com/blog/http-request-defaults)

[image: HTTP Request Defaults Demo]

Comment: I have tried different HTTP transport but it does not work for me. I am would like to ask whether there are something which can be done in code or server side.